# Presto: Slow SQL Server query response

Tags: sql-server, presto

I'm having trouble setting up the SQL Server connector for Presto db. It is taking 20+ seconds to execute a simple select statement (including planning and running time). Here is a screenshot presto dashboard (The actual sql server execution time is under 50ms.)

[image: The actual sql server execution time is under 50ms.]

Table temp contains just 2 records.

Here is my SQL Server connector config:

```
connector.name=sqlserver
connection-url=jdbc:sqlserver://[server address]
connection-user=user
connection-password=password
```

Presto config:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE RESULT**

```
Fragment 1 [SOURCE]                                                                                                                                                                    
     CPU: 10.87ms, Input: 2 rows (44B); per task: avg.: 2.00 std.dev.: 0.00, Output: 2 rows (44B)                                                                                       
     Output layout: [id, col1]                                                                                                                                                   
     Output partitioning: SINGLE []                                                                                                                                                     
     Execution Flow: UNGROUPED_EXECUTION                                                                                                                                                
     - TableScan[sqlserver:sqlserver:dbo.temp:sns_viz:dbo:temp, originalConstraint = true] => [id:char(10), col1:varchar]                                                        
             Cost: {rows: ? (?), cpu: ?, memory: 0.00, network: 0.00}                                                                                                                   
             CPU fraction: 100.00%, Output: 2 rows (44B)                                                                                                                                
             Input avg.: 2.00 rows, Input std.dev.: 0.00%                                                                                                                               
             id := JdbcColumnHandle{connectorId=sqlserver, columnName=id, jdbcTypeHandle=JdbcTypeHandle{jdbcType=-15, columnSize=10, decimalDigits=0}, columnType=char(10)} 
             col1 := JdbcColumnHandle{connectorId=sqlserver, columnName=col1, jdbcTypeHandle=JdbcTypeHandle{jdbcType=-9, columnSize=2147483647, decimalDigits=0}, columnType=varchar}
```

I've tested MySQL connector with similar configuration and it works perfectly fine. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What query are you executing?

Comment: Select * from table_name;

Comment: Could you please run "EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from table_name;" and share the output?

Comment: @KamilBajda-Pawlikowski I have added the result to the question.

Comment: Thank you! It's clear that the query execution itself is not an issue at all.
Are you able to look into your SQL Server instance to find out whether there are any other SQL statements run there during the planning time in Presto? For example some information schema- / metadata-related operations?

Comment: They do execute but I wait for them to complete before executing my query. They are also taking alot of time